# Change iOS Deployment Target [Titanium]

Tags: ios, deployment, titanium

I just want to know if there is a way to change the iOS deployment target to 6.1 instead of 4.0.

I tried setting the min-ios-version in tiapp.xml file; but then when I open the .xcodeproject file; under iOS deployment platform it still says 4.0.

Comment: you should download and install Xcode 4.6.3 with iOS SDK 6.1

Comment: I do have xCode 4.6.3

Answer (score 0):

You should use Xcode for this and change the deployment target. Read [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/110801/how-to-set-iphone-minimum-os-requirements-not-to-be-31) link. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

you could now set it within titanium studio Go on as

1)Right click on project

2)Go to run as and then Run configuration

There you can change device and os version

thanks